# How to read excel file from remote server using python ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a local machine connected with internet.From my local machine i can access different machine or remote server.
On this remote server i have a excel/csv file.
I want to read this excel/csv file from my local machine using python programming. 
How to read the excel/csv file located in different machine/remote server.

Comment: Is is in an FTP server? Is is available via HTTP? What have you done so far? Can you provide a MVE?

Comment: It is available through SFTP. I am using linux machine

Comment: You have not even attempted to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `pysftp` package might help. Check out [this writeup](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-secure-ftp-module), which includes code examples of authenticating and fetching a file.